# Apple Social Login: is s there an Apple "user info" endpoint URL?

Tags: oauth-2.0, apple-push-notifications

I'm currently implementing various Social Login flows in Salesforce.
(*disclaimer: I'm aware that Apple/Google integrations exist natively in SF, but for some technical reason I have to develop a custom implementation*)

Such an implementation essentially requires 3 steps:

1. get an authorization code
2. get an access token using the authorization code
3. get user info using the access token

I managed to implement **Google** Social Login perfectly.

I'm struggling with step 3 for **Apple**.
Talking about getting user info, **Google** provides this endpoint URL: `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo`

After having done some research, I can't find the equivalent for **Apple**.

Can anybody help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct equivalent for Apple to get the user information. Rather, the Sign in with Apple flow sends the user information in the first response from the Authorization endpoint. The flow is like this:

1. User clicks on "Sign in with Apple" in your web app
2. Your backend constructs a request to `https://appleid.apple.com/auth/authorize` with the clientId and state and redirects the browser to that
3. Apple serves up a login page then asks if the user wants to share their name and email with your app
4. Apple's login page uses Javascript to send a  POST to your backend with `x-www-form-urlencoded` parameters: the authorization code, your state, plus a JSON encoded `user` parameter.
5. Your backend then sends a POST to `https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token` to exchange the code for an authorization token.

With Google you would query the info endpoint after step 5 to get the user name, but with Apple you must capture the `user` parameter from step 4. This is the only place you will get the user data - and it is only provided the first time the user signs into your app with Apple.

The parameters to the POST in step 4 look like this after URL decoding:

```
state=4891aaebb8b9066e
code=c5600a9e2838d4dfc8829e51ede2f7ed0.0.rrwqr.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
user={"name":{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Smith"},"email":"john@example.com"}
```

Comment: Why Apple provides access_token in response https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token at all? It can not be used anywehere. Btw for your info, you do not need to https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token bcs when redirecting to authorization you can set 'response_type' => 'code id_token` (added id_token) and you will have immediately data after redirection to redirect_uri. There will be post field id_token - but to trust data you need to verify it integrity by apples public key. Btw in Google your are wrong too because user data are also in id_token and can be trusted because of server-server request

Comment: See more about google id_token after request accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token  https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect#obtainuserinfo

Comment: I am not seeing this `user` object in the authorize call response, Do we need to provide an additional scope for that?